# What is meant by the phrase "positive hatred"?

Tags: word-usage

According to Merriam Webster dictionaries, **[enmity](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enmity)** means:

> **positive**, active, and typically mutual hatred or ill will

How can "hatred" be "positive"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

“Positive” doesn’t always mean “good”, which is what you might be thinking. See M-W’s definitions for “positive”- https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/positive - only definitions 6 and 8 (particularly 8) seem to have anything to do with “goodness”. The meaning of *positive* here I think is what the dictionary has under definition 2c:

> c(1) : INCONTESTABLE
>
> > positive proof
>
> (2) : UNQUALIFIED
>
> > a positive disgrace

“Positive hatred” means that there is no doubt about the hatred’s existence (2c1), and/or that there is nothing but hatred (2c2).